# Dialogflow required parameters

Tags: node.js, nlp, dialogflow-es, chatbot

In my dialogflow chatbot i am creating i have a scenario where a user can ask what are the available vacancies you have or they can directly ask i want to join as a project manager or something. Both are in the same intent called "jobs" and the position they  want is a required parameter. If  user don't mention the position (eg - "what are the available vacancies you have" ) it will list all available vacancies and minimum qualifications need for that vacancy and ask user to pick one (done with slotfilling for webhook.). Now since the intent is waiting for the parameter when user enter the position they like it will provide the details regarding that position. But even when user is trying to ask for something else (trying to call to a another intent or they don't have enough qualifications for that vacancy or the needed job is not listed with the available job list) since that parameter (the Job position) is not provided it ask again and again what is the position you want.

how do i call to another intent when the chatbot is waiting for a required parameter

[image]

There is a separate intent for "The job i want is not here". If i typed the exact same one i used to train that intent then i works. but if it is slightly different then it won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- make your parameter as "NOT" required by unchecking the required checkbox.
- keep webhook for slot filling.
- in the webhook, keep a track if the parameter is provided or not.
- if the intent is triggered, check programmatically for parameter and ask the user to provide it by playing with the contexts.
- if the user said something else, then there will be no "required" parameter as per Dialogflow and it will not ask repeatedly to provide the parameter.

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: It won't work well if there are two or more parameters that are required though.